The same equation giving different integrals?
I feel like I’m missing something obvious. I have checked on online integral calculators and I keep getting different answers despite the fact they are equivalent fractions.
$$\frac{1}{0.5x+5}=\frac{2}{x+10}$$
but if I integrate the left-hand side then I get something different to the right-hand side.
$$\int\frac{1}{0.5x+5} \,\Bbb dx= 2 \ln (0.5x+5) +c $$
$$\int\frac{2}{x+10} \,\Bbb dx= 2 \ln (x+10) +c $$

Recall that multiplication inside of a logarithm becomes addition outside of the logarithm.  $\ln(ab) = \ln(a)+\ln(b)$.  Your answers differ by an additive constant... i.e. a part of the $+c$.  Remember that those $+c$'s don't need to refer to the same additive constant.

Integrate from 0 to x

The answer is hidden in your constants c. The 2 functions you wrote down are the same up to a constant. This is because you´re considering indefinite integrals. For definite integrals, you would get a number, instead of a function w.r.t. $x$.

